# Can't add atomic repo to CentOS

Tags: centos

I'm trying to add the atomic repo to CentOS. I run:

```
sudo wget -q -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | sh
```

All seems to go fine.

However, when I look in /etc/yum.repos.d it's not there. And when I try to install anything with yum, it doesn't appear to be looking in the atomic repo.

**EDIT 1**

It's CentOS 5

Comment: I'm tempted to reconstruct the installation manually from the script. Which CentOS release?

Comment: @packs Do you mean you would be tempted to not use the atomic repo and get the source and compile and install it by hand?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is, it isn't working because you have `sudo` in the wrong spot.

You currently have:

```
sudo wget -q -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | sh
```

Which applies the `sudo` command to the `wget` command, but by the time it is piped into the `sh`, it's lost its root privileges. If you move the `sudo` over, it should work.

So, give this one a try:

```
wget -q -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | sudo sh
```

Comment: That did it! Scott Pack did a great job in pulling out the needed line, and Valorin figured out why it didn't work. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing that install script, I noticed a few issues that will prevent it from working. There are a few times where it tries to download files that result in an HTTP 404 error, including the actual the repository RPM! Based on the install script, you should only need to execute the following commands to successfully install the repository.

This will first install the GPG key Shinn uses to sign the packages, second download and install the files necessary to use the atomic repository, and third install the additional plesk repository. Replace `$ARCH` in step 2 with the output of the command `uname -i`, and step 3 is only necessary if you also want plesk.

1. rpm --import http://www.atomicrocketturtle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY.art.txt
2. rpm -Uvh http://atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/5/$ARCH/RPMS/atomic-release-1.0-13.el5.art.noarch.rpm
3. wget -q -O /etc/yum.repos.d/plesk.repo http://atomicorp.com/installers/repos/plesk-centos-8.repo

Comment: That gave me: error: skipping http://atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/5/i386/RPMS/atomic-release-1.0-13.el5.art.noarch.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error

Comment: Have you tried downloading it first, then installing it?